# Kafka stream enrichment when we must fetch data on the fly

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a stream of incoming events:

```
{ user: 123, itemid: 'abc', ... }
{ user: 456, itemid: 'abc', ... }
{ user: 123, itemid: 'def', ... }
{ user: 789, itemid: 'xyz', ... }
{ user: 123, itemid: 'xyz', ... }
```

and so on. We need to enrich these with data looked up by the item id (web service call), but
the lookup can be slow. On the other hand, the item data is pretty static,
so caching it for a day would not be a problem.

Now, the standard solution is to publish item data to a KTable and join, but...
We cannot get all the items - we get these from a backend system and cannot just do a "get all".
And there will be no update notifications. Imagine that the item ids are book ISBN numbers -
we cannot ask for a list of all the books in the world. And book information will only change slowly
(e.g someone fixing a classification error), and we do not need to republish events for such changes.

So, how do we do this?
My current thinking is that we partition on the itemid, do a left join with the item KTable and then, in the value joiner,
if the right value is null, do the web service lookup, return the result and publish the result to the item KTable topic.
But will this prevent us from looking up 'abc' twice?

For scale, our current dataset has around 1.5 million individual items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea seems to be sound, but I would not use a `KTable` but a custom stateful `Transformer()` that maintains the state. There is just a single input stream to the `transform()` and you do lookups into the `Transformer`s state. If the lookup fails, you to the RCP, put it into the store and also do the join for your output record.